# Convert epoch time (minute since reference time) to human readable time format

Tags: python, datetime

The question in the title seems to be familiar as I could see lot of example blog posts and SO posts. However, I couldn't find a question similar to the issue I am facing. I have a netcdf file in which variable time has a single data value `10643385`. The unit of this time variable is `minutes since 2000-01-01 00:00:00` which is different from many examples I found on the internet.I am also aware of the fact that actual value of time is `27-03-2020 05:45`.  My query is that how do I get this epoch value `int` to the date time format like `27-03-2020 05:45'. Here is the sample code I have been trying which results in the reference datetime rather than actual datetime of the file:-

`print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch_time_value)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

The above single line of code result in `1970-05-04 09:59:45`. Can some one help me to get the correct date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10643385)
```

outputs

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 5, 45)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. It worked. Waiting for another 8 min to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python epoch time is in seconds, so we must first convert this to seconds by multiplying by 60.

Python epoch time starts on 1, Jan, 1970. Since netcdf starts on 2000-01-01, we must adjust by adding the amount of seconds from 1970 to 2000 (which happens to be 946684800).

Putting these together we get:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> epoch_time_value = 10643385
>>> _epoch_time_value = epoch_time_value * 60 + 946684800
>>> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(_epoch_time_value)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2020-03-26 22:45:00
```

Then, there may be some shift (possibly +/- 12 hours) based on timezone, so make sure the timezones in your calculations are synced when you do this!

Comment: Thank for the explanation.